# Proof for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ without complexes?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

This is what I needed. Practically, a link were also okay.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: You can use [Fourier_transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)

Comment: @Jlamprong Fourier-transformation without complexes???

Comment: Yes. see [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/GZ05/03-fourier.pdf)

Comment: @Jlamprong Is it me, or complex numbers are clearly mentioned on pages 3, 5, 6, 7 and 8 of the slides you link to?

Comment: I think [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703454), while not the shortest, seems to require the fewest prerequisites.  Definitely, no complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Evaluating ζ(2) by Robin Chapman](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf) contains several proofs (~14 altogether). You can have a look through and find a nice one.

Comment: They are really good proofs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to compute the Fourier series of either $\sin$ or $x$ on $(0,2\pi)$ extended to $\mathbb R$ periodically to get the left hand side and then use Parseval's theorem to prove equivalence to the right hand side.